# how do i log in user using session based and basic auth in django rest framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using session based auth and basic auth i want to be able to login the user on creation(post) so when i create a user it gives back a session id.
I know i need to obtain a crsf token first to be able to talk to my api.

```
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

this is my create method

Answer (score 1):

You can exempt the `CsrfToken` follow this things.

## authentication.py

```
from rest_framework.authentication import SessionAuthentication

class CsrfExemptSessionAuthentication(SessionAuthentication):

    def enforce_csrf(self, request):
        return True
```

Add this file in the settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'xxxxxx.authentication.CsrfExemptSessionAuthentication',
 )}
```